# Is there project webhook event that triggers on project update such as change project name in gitlab like github and bitbucket

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I was trying to fetch project updates (eg. change name of project or group) through webhook in gitlab but i am not able to get changes that i made in project name or group name.

I tried in github and bitbucket there I am able to get repository changes through repository webhook event, is there any event that supports project changes.

Answer (score 0):

i think your looking for [System Hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/system_hooks.html#repository-update-events) which trigger when updates on repositories are performed. careful because this will enable all update events from any repo in gitlab. Afaik it cannot be done on repo level.

Comment: ok, but i can see that system hook option only visible in onprem version when i logged in there as an  admin

Comment: i could not find the same features for SaaS GitLab. From this thread https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-saas-configure-a-webhook-to-apply-to-all-groups-projects-in-the-account/62605 it says it's not possible. Looking at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html#group-member-events it does not trigger when settings are changed. I'm not using SaaS so i can not say for sure if it is not possible.